# Calculating number of nodes in BST using recursion c++

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to find the number of nodes in a BST using recursion. Here is my code

```
struct Node{
    int key;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;

    Node(){
        int key = 0;
        struct Node* left = nullptr;
        struct Node* right = nullptr;
    }
};
```

src_root is the address of the root node of the tree.

```
int BST::countNodes(Node* src_root, int sum){

        if((src_root==root && src_root==nullptr) || src_root==nullptr)
            return 0;
        else if(src_root->left==nullptr || src_root->right==nullptr)
            return sum;
        return countNodes(src_root->left, sum + 1) + countNodes(src_root->right, sum + 1) + 1;
        }
```

However my code only seems to work if there are 3 nodes. Anything greater than 3 gives wrong answer. Please help me find out what's wrong with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a long time ago since I made anything in C/C++ so if there might be some syntax errors.

```
int BST::countNodes(Node *scr_root)
{
    if (scr_root == null) return 0;
    return 1 + countNodes(scr_root->left) + countNodes(scr_root->right);
}
```

I think that will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You have several logical and structural problems in your implementation.  Casperah gave you the "clean" answer that I assume you already found on the web (if you haven't already done that research, you shouldn't have posted your question).  Thus, what you're looking for is not someone else's solution, but how to fix your own.

1. Why do you pass **sum** *down* the tree?  Lower nodes shouldn't care what the previous count is; it's the parent's job to accumulate the counts from its children.  See how that's done in Casperah's answer?  Drop the extra parameter from your code; it's merely another source for error.
2. Your base case has an identically false clause: src_root==root && src_root==nullptr ... if you make a meaningful call, src_root *cannot* be both **root** and **nullptr**.
3. Why are you comparing against a global value, **root**?  Each call simply gets its own job done and returns.  When your call tree crawls back to the original invocation, the one that was called with the root, it simply does its job and returns to the calling program.  This should *not* be a special case.
4. Your *else* clause is wrong: it says that if *either* child is null, you ignore counting the other child altogether and return only the count so far.  This guarantees that you'll give the wrong answer unless the tree is absolutely balanced and filled, a total of 2^N - 1 nodes for N levels.

Fix those items in whatever order you find instructive; the idea is to learn.  Note, however, that your final code should look a lot like the answer Casperah provided.